# The name 'T' does not exist in the current context while overriding view in a nopCommerce plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plugins, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

First, for context, I'm working on a Plugin for nopCommerce.

I am overriding a view (namely `\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Views\Currency\List.cshtml`) in my plugin by creating a custom view engine. Now though that's successful, I'm having trouble loading my customized view.

One of probably several errors when app tries to load my view:

[image]

Apparently not very experienced with front-end so subsequently with how views work.

Edit: ***Created [View doesn't recognize sln project references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59824868/12468911) to better localize the issue.***

Comment: The link to the new SO question results in a 404.

Answer (score -1):

From the error message, it seems that the namespace reference is missing for 
the localization.

To resolve this error, you need to add a reference `@using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc.Razor` in your overridden view page.

Another way is to add the reference to `_ViewImports.cshtml` file under your `plugin > views` folder.

A better way is to copy `_ViewImports.cshtml` file from `\Presentation\Nop.Web\Areas\Admin\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml` and paste it to `your plugin > Views Folder`

This will resolve the error you're facing.

Comment: Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc.Razor & the _ViewImports.cshtml do not exist on my version of nopcommerce. (using v3.9)

Comment: I did try ```@using Nop.Web.Framework.ViewEngines.Razor;``` but it didn't work

Comment: @Onion - You still getting same error message or different one?.

Comment: Tbh trying to fix that error I'm now getting a weird assembly load issue: https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/topic/75401/error-on-project-run-plugin-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-systembadimage-exception

Comment: I just reverted to an old commit for now so ye this thread is still about the same issue.

Comment: I got the same error message after adding @using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc.Razor to the view page.